# Where do I see log entries in Application Insights?

Tags: .net, azure, logging, nlog, azure-application-insights

I got Application Insights up and running for my ASP.NET application. Then, I installed [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget/) package and added `ApplicationInsightsTarget` to my NLog configuration. It seems to be working fine. At least I can see outgoing requests to `dc.services.visualstudio.com:443`. Now, where on Azure Portal do I see my log entries? **APPLICATION INSIGHTS -> Activity log** page is always empty.

**Update:**
The issue was I thought all regular NLog messages should appear as they were in terms of event category, i.e. Info, Warn, etc. But the reality was ANY NLog messages went as TRACE entries in Application Insights. Kind of disappointing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have tested Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget on my local and get the trace information in Application Insights. We can get this information via click **Your Application insigths -> Overview -> Search**, like the following screenshot.
[image]

For how to use Nlog in Application Insights, please read [this article](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging).

Answer (score 2):

Technically if you add some another logger package for AI, new kind of appender is added. Internally the appender calls Telemetry methods from Application Insights and add some additional information to request or exception (using the AI properties).

The answer is: You can find all your telemetries on one place in the Azure portal as usual. For example in Diagnostics Search or in the aggregated graphs with a small delay.